# Function like assert.Contains by stretchr/testify but ignore case and whitespace

Tags: go, testify, go-testing

For example, I have this test here

```
assert.Contains(t, "HELLO     WORLD", "hello world)
```

and I want this to return **true**. Obviously, I can clean up the string with `strings.TrimSpace()`, `strings.ReplaceAll()`, and `strings.ToLower()` beforehand. Although it gets cumbersome when I have dozens of these. Is there any cleaner way to achieve this? Or can I possibly modify or create a customized `assert.NormalizedContains()`? Thank you for the input!

Comment: Just write a function that does whatever you need and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `func normalize(s string) string` and use that together with `assert.Contains`, for example:

```golang
func normalize(s string) string {
    return strings.ToLower(strings.Join(strings.Fields(s), ""))
}

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    assert.Contains(t, normalize("HELLO     WORLD"), "hello world")
    // or you might want to normalize both:
    assert.Contains(t, normalize("HELLO     WORLD"), normalize("hello world"))
}
```

If you're really doing this a lot, you could create a custom `func assertNormalizedContains(t *testing.T, haystack, needle string)` and just use that instead of `assert.Contains`. Though I'd argue that's not as clear.

Comment: That's what I end up doing too! I was wondering if there could be some other function I can "extend" but I agree this might be the cleanest way. Thanks for the help!